# Meaning of R on top of arrow in functions

Tags: functions

I was reading some paper and I found out something of which I cannot find the correct meaning. What does $A\xleftarrow{R}B$ means in functions notation? The $R$ on top of the function throw me off, I really want to know what it really means

EDIT: the paper in quetion is [Craig Gentry's PhD Thesis](https://crypto.stanford.edu/craig/craig-thesis.pdf), page 8, Recrypt algorithm

Comment: Can you link the paper?

Comment: It often means $R$ **is** the function, but it depends on context.

Comment: Most likely (but we need context to determine that) there is a reason for writing it in that order, and it means the same as if everything had been swapped horizontally, i.e. it had been $B\overset{R}{\rightarrow} A$.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity yes, I understand that, my problem is with the $R$ on top, I can't grasp if it's the function's name or something else

Comment: This is not function notation, but rather pseudocode conventions where $\leftarrow$ means “assign” (or define). As for the $R$, I don’t know. It almost looks like a typo to me, but I can’t tell.

Comment: Also, welcome to MSE, and note for next time that more context from the start would have been helpful here :)